# How to structure BDD scenarios for situations with a lot of variables

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, bdd, gherkin, katalon-studio

Our team is new to BDD development/specification, and from a testautomation perspective we would like to get some advice on setting up BDD scenarios (and the Steps) in a situation where there are a lot of variables, like with forms.

Here is the situation: A form to create employees, which consists of multiple subjects like personal information, job details, salary, etc.

A possible scenario outline the team has come up with:

**Given** I want to add a new employee
**And** the job title is "*jobtitle*"
**When** I submit the form
**Then** a notification is sent to "*manager*"

**Examples:**
  |***jobtitle***|***manager***|
  |Developer|John Doe|

The steps above describe only the deciding factors for the outcome of the scenario. So what name a person might have or what salary he/she will earn won't affect the scenario. However, in another scenario a different field might be the deciding factor, like someones department. In this case, how would be bundle the scenarios or the underlying steps, so we can re-use as much as possible? Because even though in this exaple the jobtitle is the deciding factor, we still need to fill in all other mandatory fields to be able to submit the form. Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define some types of employee and get the right details in the code.

for example: junior admin, senior admin, manager assistant
Each description tells something about job details, salary and role.

Based on these you generate the salary and job description in a method.

In your bdd scenario:
Given I have an **junior admin** employee
where **junior admin** is a parameter that you can use to get what data type you need and create the user.

```
    /**
     * @When /^I have an (junior admin|senior hr) employee$/
     */
    public function iHaveAnEmployee($employeeType)
    {
        // generate data for employee
        $employee = someMethodThatGeneratesEmployeeDetails($employeeType);

       // create the employee
       someMethodThatCreatesTheEmployee($employee);
    }
```

If you want to see those details in the report then find a way to print them there after the step runs.

Comment: I would need a step for each type in the Steps right? Because the Junior can become a Senior and admin can become support?

Comment: No, just use parameters

Comment: Yes, but what if i don't want to use a parameter and leave it empty? That wont work? The goal is to make the life of the persons easier to write the scenario's. You dont want them coming up with all these parameters that dont matter for the test.

Comment: The parameter is just a name that describe the persona so that it can use different details else you will need to write steps for each type. You can specify the parameters in such a manner that they are suggested by the IDE, in my example, when I type `I have an` then the IDE will suggest those types of employees, so they are easy to use. I am sure you can find a way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable for parameters

Ex:

```
    Scenario Outline:
    Given I am on the new user registration page
    When I enter invalid data on the page
    |personal information| job details| salary|  //parameters
    Then close the browser.

    Examples:
    |jobtitle|manager|
    |Developer|John Doe|


        @When("^I enter invalid data on the page$") 
           public void enterData(DataTable table){ 
              //Initialize data table 
              List<list> data = table.raw();
              System.out.println(data.get(0).get(0));//personal information
    System.out.println(data.get(0).get(1));//job details
    System.out.println(data.get(0).get(2));//salary
```

Comment: Isnt the problem with this approach that you always have to provide this information? We wouldnt want to make scenarios more complex than neccesary.